# How can I use catch properly?

Tags: haskell

When I use catch, I get this warning:

```
Warning: In the use of `catch'
         (imported from System.IO.Error):
         Deprecated: "Please use the new exceptions variant, Control.Exception.catch"
```

I've tried to use Control.Exception.catch instead, but I've been chasing errors down too many rat holes.   Can someone post an example where the 2nd arg of catch catches the UnsupportedOperation error thrown by getTemporaryDirectory?

```
tempdir <- catch (getTemporaryDirectory) 
                 (\e -> return ".")
```

Also, how do I use the catch syntax in the catch docs:

```
catch f (\e -> ... (e :: SomeException) ...)
```

I've tried every variation of that syntax I can think of, and I always get an error; it does not seem possible to enclose a type annotation(?) in parentheses like that in a lambda.  Extremely poor documentation in my opinion.  Unfortunately, that seems to be the standard that doc writers aspire to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple trick that works without any extensions is:

```
m `catch` (\e -> do
    let _ = e :: IOException  -- or whatever exception type you want to catch
    doStuff )
```

If you use the value `e`, then you can also just put the type annotation wherever you use it:

```
m `catch` (\e -> do
    print (e :: IOException)
    doStuff )
```

Comment: Isn't it considered bad practice to catch all exceptions?  I'm trying to limit the catch to catch only UnsupportedOperation. When I use e::UnsupportedOperation, I get type constructor or class `UnsupportedOperation'.  I'll also note that I've looked high and lo in the haskell docs for a list of haskell exceptions to no avail.

Comment: Oh!  You catch `IOException`, and then you use the functions from `System.IO.Error` to determine which kind of `IOException` it is.  However, the latest `base` does not have an `UnsupportedOperation` `IOException`.  It does have an illegal operation error, which you can test using `isIllegalOperation`, but I need to check to see if that is the correct exception to catch for that function.  Hold on.

Comment: @7stud Sorry, I cannot figure out which exception it will throw. :(  Your best bet for now is just catching `IOException`.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez: [Apparently, it's GHC-specific](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/GHC-IO-Exception.html#IOErrorType), which explains why I couldn't find it anywhere in the documentation. It looks like a pain to target specifically, though. Catching `IOException` is probably good enough in this case.

Comment: @hammar looking at the definition, I think catching `IOException` is the only option, since there isn't a separate `UnsupportedOperation` type.  It appears that `IOException` is a leaf of the exception tree.

Comment: Can someone post an answer with a complete example that catches an IOException (using Control.Exception.catch? Thanks.

Comment: @7stud I modified my answer to catch `IOException`.

Comment: @Gabriel Gonzalez, Thanks for hanging in there with me!